# Trying to find a counterexample about distance in topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Consider $n$ dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, its topology is usual topology, which induced from distance $d(x,y)=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-y_i)^2}$. In topology space $(\mathbb{R}^n,d)$, a sequence $a_n$ converges to a point $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Given a subset $A=\{a_n:n=1,2,\ldots\}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, its closure is $\bar{A}=A\cup\{a\}$ by definition. Another subset $B\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ does not intersect with $\bar{A}$. Does the distance $$\inf\{d(x,y):x\in A,y\in B\}>0$$ always hold?

I tried to set $A=\{(\frac{1}{n},0,\ldots,0)\}$ and $B=(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2^n},0,\ldots,0)$, although $\inf d(x,y)=\inf\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}}=0$, but I found if $n\to\infty$, $B$ tends to $\{0\}\subset\bar{A}$.

Edited:

By the below answer we found a counterexample when $B$ is open set. I was wondering the situation when $B$ is closed set. Two closed subsets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ do not intersect, maybe by $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Hausdorff, the distance $d(A,B)$ cannot be zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity, set $n=1$, then consider $A=\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, so that $\overline A=\{0\}\cup A$, and $B=\{1+\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, so that $\overline{A}\cap B=\emptyset$, but it is still easy to see that $d(A,B)=0$.

**edited after OP's comment** Another counterexample can be obtained considering $A=\mathbb{N}$, so that $\overline{A}=A=\mathbb{N}$, and $B=\{n+\frac{1}{2n}\mid n\in\mathbb{n}\}$, so that $\overline{B}=B$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$. In this case, one can still see that $d(A,B)=0$.

Comment: But according to the definition of Euclidean space, shouldn't $d(A,B)$ be $\sqrt{n}\to\infty$?

Comment: Distance is defined by the "closest" points not the points where they converge to

Comment: @CunyiNan $d(A, B)$ is defined as the infimum of distances between elements of $A$ and $B$. Then you can get arbitrarily close to $1 = 1/1 \in A$ with $1 + 1/n \in B$, so the distance is zero.

Comment: Got it, I once misinterpreted it as distance of two vectors calculated one by one.

Comment: Apologize for missing another condition, what if $B$ is a closed set?

Comment: @CunyiNan I edited the answer